# NHibernate Reusable QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

To keep my queries self-contained and potentially reusable, I tended to do this in NH2:

```
public class FeaturedCarFinder : DetachedCriteria
{
    public FeaturedCarFinder(int maxResults) : base(typeof(Car))
    {
        Add(Restrictions.Eq("IsFeatured", true));
        SetMaxResults(maxResults);
        SetProjection(BuildProjections());
        SetResultTransformer(typeof(CarViewModelMessage));
    }
}
```

I'd like to use QueryOver now that I've moved to NH3, but I'm not sure how to do the above using QueryOver?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone on the NH Users list gave me the answer:

```
public class FeaturedCarFinder : QueryOver<Car, Car> 
{ 
    public FeaturedCarFinder(int maxResults) 
    { 
        Where(c => c.IsFeatured); 
        Take(maxResults); 
        BuildProjections(); 
        TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(CarViewModelMessage))); 
    } 
    private void BuildProjections() 
    { 
        SelectList(l => 
            l.Select(c => c.IsFeatured) 
            //... 
            ); 
    } 
}
```

Very similar to using DetachedCriteria as a base class, but note the use of QueryOver (i.e. the two type-argument version) rather than just QueryOver as the base class.